# Changing default value of client_max_body_size in dockerized nginx container is not reflected while uploading file > 1MB with 413 Entity Too Large err

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, http-status-code-413

Hope someone can help me with the error I could not resolve. 
Scenario:
Changing default upload limit 1MB by using **client_max_body_size 10m;** works without any problem while uploading file **without using docker container**. But **when using it with nginx:latest docker container** the setting configured for the docker is **not being reflected** and 413 Request Entity Too Large is being produced while uploading files > 1MB(nginx default limit).

There are three containers

1. nginx
2. mariadb
3. express pm2 app using axios

P.S upload limit is already handled for express middleware.

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: true, limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '10mb' }));
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: app_nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf
      - ./nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
```

app.conf

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

 location / {
  ...
  client_max_body_size 10m;

  ...
 }

}
```